# How to resize image with imagick php

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

With imagick command, i want to resize image form 2Mb to 200KB, i tried:

```
convert a.jpg -strip -define jpeg:extent=200k a1.jpg
```

And it work. But i want to use imagick function of php to resize blob image.

Php's documentation regarding the [resizeImage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resizeimage.php) method require width and height.

How can resize blob image from 2Mb to 200Kb like the command line above.

I tried:

```
    $imageBlob = file_get_contents('a.jpg');
    $image = new \Imagick();
    $image->readImageBlob($imageBlob);
    $height = $image->getImageHeight();
    $width = $image->getImageWidth();
    $image->resizeImage( $width, $height,  \Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1 );
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mime = finfo_buffer($finfo, $image->getImageBlob());
    $mime == "image/svg" && $mime.= "+xml";
    $base64 =  "data:$mime;base64," . base64_encode($image->getImageBlob());
    echo "<img src=\"".$base64.'">';die;
```

But this doesn't reduce the size from 2Mb to 200Kb

Comment: The command-line command you show does not decrease the image size to 200kB. It resizes the image to be 200 pixels wide.

Comment: To resize to a particular file size for JPG only, see -define jpeg:extent at https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#jpg_write

Comment: @Mark Setchell, i have been updated script

Comment: @ fmw42, i want to use Imagick of Php to resize it, instead of command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested this, but am fairly sure you can use [setOption](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setoption.php) like this to set the upper limit for a JPEG's filesize:

```
$imagick->setOption('jpeg:extent', $extent);
```